# React onKeyPress fire default event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

I have a control where I would like to execute some logic before and after a key press.

```
onKeyPress={event => {
...
}}
```

I can do `event.preventDefault();`, to cancel a default event, or not use it to not cancel it. However, I would like to execute some logic before and after the default event. `onKeyUp` doesn't seem to do quite what I want. Any other way?

To be more specific:
I am using Editable control from Slate JS (https://docs.slatejs.org/). In the browser it creates a regular `div` element (the event is `React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>`). One thing that doesn't work well out of the box is the inline formatting. If a user pressed Bold button, and there is no selection, and the cursor is not in the middle of a word, the application should apply the bold style to the next character entered (like in Word). So, I have to wait the next character, and conditionally apply formatting to it. That's why I need to keep some state marking if we are in "preparation for bold mode", flagged when Bold is pressed under described conditions. In the `onKeyPress` event, I check if that flag has been set, and if yes, I remember the current position to start the bold marking. What I would like to do is immediately fire the default event to get the actual character, then finish up with defining the end of the selection, applying the bold marking in the range, and placing the caret at the end. Now I have to use `onKeyUp` to finish up with the selection and do the marking. This delays formatting if the user holds the key and characters are displayed unbolded until release.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why `onKeyUp` and the other events don't do 'quite what you want`? What exactly are you trying to do before and after a key press?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I am dealing with formatting some text, I have to start the process before the character event and complete it immediately after on that specific character. I implemented the `onKeyUp` solution, besides not being quite elegant, if the user holds the key the formatting is applied only when the key is released. This leaves the stream of characters unformatted which are created as the user holds the key, and they are formatted all at once when released. I am not aware of any other events.

Comment: There’s also onKeyDown. If you can update the question to provide more specifics about what you’re trying to do we can provide more help.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody AFAIK onKeyDown does the same thing as onKeyPress except it fires for modifier keys too. This wouldn't bring me any benefit over OnKeyPress. I could describe the specifics of the situation, but I don't think they will be React-specific and would not create a better solution than the one already with 3 mentioned events. I would like a general solution, something like `event.fireDefault()` or something.

Comment: Unless we understand what you’re trying to accomplish we can’t recommend anything specific. We need to understand the problem. All we know is you want to do something before/after a keyPress, but that’s pretty vague. Are we dealing with an input?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that helps. It's still unclear what we want to accomplish though. Let's say I'm using your app and I press the 'F' key. What should happen?

Comment: I have added more information about the process. Perhaps that helps to clarify more.